# Euler angle to Multivector

Tags: linear-algebra

What’s the formula to go from euler angles over to Multivector, and are they the same as rotors?

I have some familiarity with quaternions but I don’t like that they have to divide the angles by 2 prior to taking a cosine and sine given the potential rounding errors that can ensue on computers, especially since if you’re going to get the results back and try to convert it back to a readable Euler angle you have to guess at one of two possible orientations of the pitch angle. So I am looking out for a better system of rotation for my apps.

Answer (score 1):

Rotors are a special case of multivectors (they're bivectors of unit length) which you would use for rotations in essentially the same way you would use the quaternions (see [Let's remove Quaternions from every 3D Engine (An Interactive Introduction to **Rotors** from Geometric Algebra)](http://marctenbosch.com/quaternions/) for detail about rotors).

Quaternions or rotors are usually used instead of Euler angles because they do not suffer from [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock), so many would recommend avoiding Euler angles if possible. But if you must convert between the two, there is information/some code at [the Wikipedia page for conversion between quaternions and Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles). You might also find the [Conversion Euler to Quaternion](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToQuaternion/index.htm) and [Conversion Quaternion to Euler](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/) pages on Martin John Baker's ["EuclideanSpace" website](https://www.euclideanspace.com/) useful.

Whatever code/reference you use, make sure that the conventions for the angles and quaternions/rotors match the ones you intend to use.